# clickAtXPath not working in laravel(5.8) Dusk

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-dusk, laravel-dusk2

### **Dusk Error**

> Dusk is throwing this error while using clickAtXPath

- BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method [clickAtXPath].

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the `clickAtXPath` method does not exist on whatever you're calling it from.

Looking at Laravel Dusk in 5.8, there is no `clickAtXPath` documented; https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/dusk#using-the-mouse

Looking through their docs, it looks like it was introduced in Laravel 7; https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/dusk#using-the-mouse

You will need to update your application if you'd like to use `clickAtXPath`.

Comment: so what should I do to call xpath in laravel 5.8.

Comment: I'm unable to update project on laravel 7or +

Comment: Well that method does not exist in Laravel 5.8.
To use it, you will need to add the method yourself or find an alternative.